# How do I json encode all the info available in the parser object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, whois, whois-ruby

I am very new to ruby and rails. I am trying to output all the parsed whois info to json output. I have the following:

```
class WhoisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    c = Whois::Client.new
    record = c.lookup("google.com")
    parser = record.parser
    created = parser.created_on
    msg = {:created => created}
    render :json => msg
  end
end
```

Output:

```
{"created":"1997-09-15T00:00:00.000-07:00"}
```

However, the parser has a LOT more info available....without knowing all the fields available, how do I dump all the keys/values to json?

I've tried:

```
class WhoisController < ApplicationController
  def index
    c = Whois::Client.new
    record = c.lookup("google.com")
    parser = record.parser
    msg = {:whois => parser}
    render :json => msg
  end
end
```

But end up getting:

```
SystemStackError in WhoisController#index
```

EDIT:

I've also tried:

```
parser.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  puts attr_name
end
```

But end up getting another error:

```
undefined method `attributes' for #<Whois::Parser:0x00007fc030d74018>
```

Both Python and Go (through reflection) can do this. What is the Ruby way to achieve this?

EDIT:

```
class WhoisController < ApplicationController
    def index
        c = Whois::Client.new
        record = c.lookup("google.com")
        parser = record.parser
        msg = {}
        for x_prop in Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES
            msg[x_prop] = parser.send(x_prop)
        end
        render :json => msg
    end
end
```

This works ONLY if all the properties exist on parser. However, some domain names don't have all the properties and will result in:

```
Unable to find a parser for property `registrant_contacts'
```

I then try to set it only if that property exists:

```
msg = {}
for x_prop in Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES
  parser.has_attribute?(:x_prop) 
    msg[x_prop] = parser.send(x_prop) 
end
render :json => msg
```

I get another error:

```
undefined method `has_attribute?'
```

EDIT #3:

I've also tried:

```
msg = {}
for prop in Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES
  msg[prop] = parser.send(prop) if parser.respond_to?(prop)
end
render :json => msg
```

This still fails if the property is missing in parser. ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class WhoisController < ApplicationController
    def index
        c = Whois::Client.new
        record = c.lookup("google.com")
        parser = record.parser
        msg = {}
        for x_prop in Whois::Parser::PROPERTIES
            msg[x_prop] = parser.send(x_prop)
        end
        render :json => msg
    end
end
```

in few cases something properties can be empty and cause an error, to escape this:

```
begin
    msg[x_prop] = parser.send(x_prop)
rescue
    # do nothing
end
```

Comment: On a couple of them I get "Unable to find a parser for property `registrant_contacts'
"

Comment: parser.has_attribute?(:prop)
  msg[prop] = parser.send(prop)   I get undefined method `has_attribute?'

Comment: @MarissaLevy just use a try catch, like my edit on answe

Comment: thx for helping a newb....another bounty coming your way when I am allowed to reward it.

Comment: The question here is: Why use a *for* loop when you can use [`#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-each)? Or [`#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) for that matter.

Comment: `for...in` is very unidiomatic for Ruby.  It's not wrong, but using iterators such as @JohanWentholt's suggestion generally leads to more concise and comprehensible code.  Also, checking for the ability to perform a task (`if..else..end`) is generally more performant to to the point than rescuing.  Rescue is better used to catch `exceptions`, that which is unexpected, not to handle expected failures.

Comment: The other issue with `for...in` is that it doesn't create a new scope. All variables set in the scope (including `x_prop`) are still available after iteration. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour at times. Whereas using an iterator will add a new scope over the current scope, allowing you to shadow outer variables or set variables that are only available while iterating. In some cases you might want to use `for...in`, but generally speaking if you don't have a valid reason you use `#each`.

Answer (score 0):

For `SystemStackError in WhoisController#index`:

I think it is because you are calling `whois` with Whois again at `record = Whois.whois("google.com")`. Try `record = whois("google.com")`.

For `` undefined method `attributes' for #<Whois::Parser:0x00007fc030d74018> ``:
attributes method does not exit for the whois parser.
See https://whoisrb.org/docs/v3/parser-properties/ .

Comment: Whois.whois is valid...also whois.lookup is also valid. I was mixing and matching. I've edited the samples.

Comment: so, there is no way to iterate through all the fields? In python and go there are ways to do it.

Comment: @MarissaLevy I wouldn't say there is no way. But you will have to write the loop yourself to iterate over the parser properties. Sometimes some libraries have minor differences across the functions/methods they provide for multiple languages.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `methods` or `inspect`.

```
    c = Whois::Client.new
    record = c.lookup("google.com")
    parser = record.parser
    render json: parser.methods.to_json
```

```
    render json: parser.inspect.to_json
```